# How to use cross-domain in Sharepoint Online in O365 - No Farm

Tags: office-365, web-services, forms-services, infopath-data-connections

I've recently migrated from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint Online in O365. I used to upload my InfoPath forms at the Farm at Manage Form Templates.

Since I don't have Farm anymore how can I upload a InfoPath form which require a admin approval due the cross-domain with a WebService?